# Unit testing parallel function using moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I've got basic interface, and a class that takes it implementation in constructor, then fetches some data sequentialy or parallely depending on input.

```
    public interface ISomeService
    {
        List<int> FetchSomeData(int a);
    }      

    public class SomeClass
    {
        private ISomeService sr { get; }

        public SomeClass(ISomeService sr) => this.sr = sr;

        public int DoMagic(bool paralell)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            if (paralell)
            {
                Parallel.For(0, 10, (x) =>
                {
                    sum += sr.FetchSomeData(x).Sum(z => z);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    sum += sr.FetchSomeData(i).Sum(z => z);
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
```

then i've got test:

```
    [Test]
    public void DoTest()
    {

        var service = new Mock<ISomeService>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        service.Setup(x => x.FetchSomeData(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(() => new List<int> { 3 });

        var someClass = new SomeClass(service.Object);

        var notParallel = someClass.DoMagic(false);

        var parallel = someClass.DoMagic(true);

        Assert.AreEqual(30, notParallel);

        Assert.AreEqual(30, parallel);
    }
```

And the problem:

NotParallel results are always the same ( 30 ), but in parallel case there results vary ( sometimes 15, other time 21 etc ).
What may be the problem? How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the variable sum from multiple threads.
Here are some options how to make this thread-safe: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d87c1085-cacb-4d82-826f-4151bf967f86/parallelfor-with-sum?forum=parallelextensions